# HTA - How to trigger the find dialog at the click of a button?

Tags: search, vbscript, hta

- I was wondering how to trigger the find dialog box from an open HTA window using a submit button?

If I manually input Ctrl F, this triggers the box, so I'm hoping it's achievable via a button.

The below is the vbscript code I've tried using, similar to an excel VBA sub I've used in the past but it doesn't work.

```
Sub SubSearch

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Dialogs(IEDialogFind).Show

End Sub
```

I've also tried using `sendkeys "^F"` and this doesn't work either.

- If there is a way of embedding the box into the HTA session, this is fine also but otherwise, just the trigger for the dialog box please!

Comment: Were you able to get this to work using my answer below?

Comment: Hello...I'm on holiday this week but will get back to you on this asap! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendKeys` should work. Here's a simple HTA that uses `SendKeys` to display the `Find` dialog box:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTA Test</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="ShowFind()">Click me</button>
</body>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub ShowFind()
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "^f"
    End Sub
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I was running an external VBscript and calling it from the HTA (not sure why I was doing it that way now I'm thinking about it!) - Your method did the trick, I'm guessing it just didn't like controlling it from outside the HTA app...Thanks for your help!